# How do I access variables from form_valid in get_success_url in a FormView?

Tags: django, python-3.x

After a user submits my form, I want to redirect the user to one of two URLs depending on the form input. Here is my code:

```
class MyClass(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    form_class = MyForm


    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
        self.special_id = form.cleaned_data.get('special_id')
        return response

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.special_id:
             next_page = reverse_lazy('home:home', kwargs={'special_id': self.special_id})
        else:
             initial_link = reverse_lazy('home:home')
             next_page = '{}?title={}'.format(initial_link, self.title)


        return next_page
```

This code above does not work. One problem is that `get_success_url` doesn't recognize the variables `self.special_id` or `self.title`. How can I redirect users to different pages depending on the values in the form?

Comment: create `def __init__(self):` and place `self.special_id = None` and `self.title = None`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this:

```
class MyClass(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    form_class = MyForm


    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):

        title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
        special_id = form.cleaned_data.get('special_id')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url(title, special_id))

    def get_success_url(self, title=None, special_id=None):
        if special_id:
             next_page = reverse_lazy('home:home', kwargs={'special_id': self.special_id})
        else:
             initial_link = reverse_lazy('home:home')
             next_page = '{}?title={}'.format(initial_link, title)

        return next_page
```

Because, when you call `super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)`, it will call `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url(title, special_id))`. So you can simply do that part yourself without needing to call `super`. Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55).

### OR

You can try like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
    self.special_id = form.cleaned_data.get('special_id')
    return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)  # call super at the end

def get_success_url(self):
    if self.special_id:
         next_page = reverse_lazy('home:home', kwargs={'special_id': self.special_id})
    else:
         initial_link = reverse_lazy('home:home')
         next_page = '{}?title={}'.format(initial_link, self.title)
    return next_page
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instance variables like this:

```
class MyClass(FormView):
  template_name = 'my_template.html'
  form_class = MyForm

  def __init__(self):
    self.title = None
    self.special_id = None

  def form_valid(self, form):
    self.title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
    self.special_id = form.cleaned_data.get('special_id')
    return super().form_valid(form) 
    # for python 2: return super(MyClass, self).form_valid(form) 
  def get_success_url(self):
    if self.special_id:
        next_page = reverse_lazy('home:home', kwargs={'special_id': self.special_id})
    else:
        response = 
        initial_link = reverse_lazy('home:home')
        next_page = '{}?title={}'.format(initial_link, self.title)

    return next_page
```

Comment: Thanks, but the reassignment of those variables in the def get_success_url(self) function still isn't recognized.

Comment: I don't see why can't you reassign them. you are doing something wrong. show me what is not working.

Comment: @henrich Can you please tell me how are you reassigning them ? you have to do `self.special_id = your_value`